# OAuth Sign In with Twitter

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, twitter-oauth

I wish to enable user to sign in to my web page using their Twitter account, and at the same time I will query their ID, Name and eMail. This can be achieved easily using Facebook and Google. But the OAuth 1 API provided by Twitter is insanely difficult. Below is what I had done:

I have successfully invoke **request_token**

After that let user sign in using the **authenticate** page.

But I don't know how to proceed from here.

I tried to invoke **verify_credentials** to get Clients profile, but response was **Authorization Required**.

I tried to invoke **authorize**, but response was **forbidden**.

Twitter API document is NOT helpful at all.

Comment: **request_token** needs to exchange with **access_token** before we can call **verify_credentials**. Both tokens look the same, and confusing. **authorize** is not needed.

Comment: Did you end up solving this? From the above comment by sk, it's not clear how to exchange a request_token for an access_token.

Comment: Yes, you call he **request_token** API, after that pass the token into **access_token** API to get a new token before proceed with other API.

Comment: Do you have a code sample? I'm trying to get "Sign in with Twitter" working using only Javascript in the browser. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes is possible, but I guess you haven't look at how Twitter calculate the Signature. It is going to give you a **BIG HEADACHE!**